# Mosaic virus on pothos/hoya plant? Please help

Tags: houseplants, fungus

My pothos plant has really strange yellowing/speckling on the leaves (the leaves are yellowing with speckles of green). I have had a thrips problem recently and am concerned the pothos got the virus that way. [image]

There is also yellowing/somewhat splotchy pattern on my nearby hoya plant. Some of the leaves are also slightly disfigured.[image]

I’m so worried that this might be mosaic virus. I have also been treating both plants with neem oil due to the thrips infestation and am wondering if possibly this is leaf burn? Very high humidity in my house so perhaps fungal? New to plant care so very grateful for any thoughts.

[image]

Comment: It seems that many viruses are transmitted by thrips, as shown in this article I found https://doi.org/10.1007/s10658-005-2334-1. But I am not sure if pothos and hoya are susceptible to those.